# how to compile single file in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm doing some refactoring that made compiler temporally give errors in several files. I'd like to work with them one by one (starting with common dependencies) and need some tool to check if modification is correct.

sbt compile is inconvenient because it gives too many errors and spends much time for compiling things that have no good.

I'm searching for a way to compile single file with sbt or a method for extracting sbt side libraries definition to pass them to a normal scalac compiler

There was a similar topic: [How to compile just some files with sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647225/how-to-compile-just-some-files-with-sbt) that turned out to be source code error discussion rather that sbt functionality disclosure.

Comment: I have run into this as well. The one answer offered doesn't make it particularly convenient so I'm going to try and make a "compileOnly" command that is similar to "testOnly". If it works, I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 6):

You could add the following line to `build.sbt`:

```
sources in Compile <<= (sources in Compile).map(_ filter(_.name == "Particular.scala"))
```

Then fix `Particular.scala`, then edit `build.sbt` and put the name of the next source file. If you keep the sbt console open, `reload` will re-read the .sbt file after you modify it.

Comment: Will it work if Particular.scala depends upon some other unmodified and working code in my project?

Comment: No, but I thought that was your whole point--instead of letting sbt figure out the incremental dependencies, traverse them yourself step by step. If you want dependencies, you should really just let sbt keep working with `~compile`, even if you need to scroll to the current errors. What I do when the amount of errors gets annoying is block-comment out the faulty method bodies and put `???` on top. That compiles, satisfies return types and is easy to find at a later point in time.

Comment: For more recent versions of sbt this has to be changed to `sources in Compile ~= (_.filter(_name == "Particular.scala"))`

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to mention here that I came across sbt-compile-quick-plugin (https://github.com/etsy/sbt-compile-quick-plugin). It does what it says on the tin, just add `addSbtPlugin("com.etsy" % "sbt-compile-quick-plugin" % "1.3.0")` to your `project/plugins.sbt`, then you can just start up `sbt` and run `compileQuick /path/to/your/file`