# How to run and compile exact one test in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I'm working on a legacy project that has been written in Scala using SBT. The unit tests have been written with ScalaTest.
The problem is there is a lot of test classes that have compilation error.

I want to run only one of these test classes and I know for running only one test I should try something like this:

```
test:testOnly *myClass
```

But when I run this command, the SBT will try to compile the whole project and as I said, there's a lot of test classes that have compilation error. 
Is there any way to tell SBT exactly which classes need to be compiled and so the others will be ignored?

Comment: sbt testOnly name.DanielSmith.TestClass

Answer (score 2):

Consider defining a [single-argument custom command](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Commands.html#Single-argument+command) in `build.sbt` like so

```
commands += Command.single("compileAndTestOnly") { (state, file) =>
  s"""set sources in Test := (sources in Test).value.filter(_.name.contains("$file"))""" ::
    "test" :: state
}
```

Now run it with `compileAndTestOnly MySpec.scala`. This command modifies `Test / sources` setting to contain only a single file like so

```
sources in Test := (sources in Test).value.filter(_.name.contains(file))
```

Note `sources in Compile` is left untouched. Afterwards it executes `test` which in effect compiles and runs a single test.

This answer is inspired by [0__](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14182194/5205022).

Comment: When I run this, SBT gives me an error: 
> compileAndTestOnly RunTest.scala
<set>:1: error: value / is not a member of sbt.Configuration
Test / sources := (Test / sources).value.filter(_.name.contains("RunTest.scala"))

Comment: @DanielSmith What version of SBT are you using? Can you publish minimal reproducible example, perhaps as GitHub repo?

Comment: I use version 0.13.11, and I can not upgrade it, it's super legacy code! Unfortunately, there isn't any github repo.

Comment: @DanielSmith In SBT 0.13.x  [slash syntax](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html#Migrating+to+slash+syntax) `Test / sources` is not available so we have to write `sources in Test` instead.  Please try edited answer.

Comment: I tested it and again sbt tries to compile all classes and run every UTs.

Comment: @DanielSmith Can you execute `;reload; compileAndTestOnly MySpec.scala; show test:sources` and post the last line in output.

Comment: Here's the result:
[error] 38 errors found
[error] (rest/test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] (processing/test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] (preprocessor/test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] (runner/test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] (ore/test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 313 s, completed Oct 12, 2019 5:49:38 PM

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to instruct sbt to only compile the file that contains the test that matches your name, because it'll only know what name the test has after it's compiled -- in scala a class name and a file name don't have to have anything to do with another.

A source filter is not built-in in sbt. You will need a custom task along the lines of what @mario-galic has above.

Beware though, that will filter based on file name, not on class name.

I agree it would be a neat feature for sbt to run all tests it can even when the compilation of some files were to fail.

Answer (score -1):

You have as mentioned above the next option:

- `sbt testOnly *className` : This will run all the tests defined in that class.
- `sbt testOnly *className-- -z "test-pattern"` : It will run all the tests from that class which spec matchs the pattern defined.

Comment: It runs a single test, but it will compile all of the classes in the project and that is the problem.

Comment: for me, this command does not work. testOnly does not find anything to run. I don't mind that it compiles anything if it has to, it just seems like it doesn't work (run a single named test) in any version that i've seen online including this one