# Is it possible to compile and run only one file with sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following directory structure :

```
- src/
  |-main/
     |-scala/
       |- mypackage/
          |- mymodule.scala
          |- anothermodule.scala
```

I wonder if it's possible to run sbt like it :

```sh
$ sbt "runMain mypackage.mymodule"
```

Without compile others sources files. Because others files are draft and can't compile yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160677/how-to-compile-single-file-in-sbt?rq=1#comment101420668_14182194 something like this might work.